# I can't run Ubuntu from an external HDD

Tags: boot

I've been a Windows user all my life, but recently I've been taking a look at several Linux distros installing them on external HDDs.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 (on an external HDD) to have a look at it and it turned out I liked it. So when I was prompted with the Minimal BASH-like line editing "error", I tried to fix it following this guide: [How to Fix Minimal BASH Like Line Editing is Supported GRUB Error In Linux?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-grub-error-in-linux/)

Everything was great since then until I decided I didn't want to depend on a hard drive whenever I wanted to use Ubuntu on my laptop. I created a 350GB partition on my internal disk (where I also have Windows 10) and installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04. When the installation menu asked me to select the "Device for boot loader installation" I choose *Windows Boot Manager*. Both Windows 10 and Ubuntu loaded perfectly, no need for external dependencies.

Now, the somewhat big problem that I'm facing is that I can't run Ubuntu form the external HDD. I just want to take a look at some customization I made, that's why I don't want to reinstall it. I just need to take a final look before I format the HDD and try installing another OS.

If I set Ubuntu to load first in the boot sequence, my laptop loads the one installed on the internal HDD, even though the external is plugged.

*I've been searching for help online, but I can't get an answer, maybe I'm not addressing the issue properly. This is the first time I post to a forum, so if my problem has already been solved somewhere else, I would really appreciate you provide a link for me to take a look at it.*

Comment: Is the setting you need a config file, a control panel, or something else?

Comment: Grub was probably never installed onto the external disk, launchpad bug 396379.  With the disk plugged in, run sudo update-grub.  Then the external disk should show up in the grub menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ubfan1 ! That perfectly worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Grub was probably never installed onto the external disk, launchpad bug 396379. With the disk plugged in, from a terminal run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then the external disk should show up in the grub menu.